# SQL Server Cursor loop holding prolonged lock on the table

Tags: sql-server, loops, sqlalchemy, locking, cursor

I have a SQL Server stored procedure with these steps:

- Begin procedure
- User CURSOR to loop thru a small list (say 50)
- Open CURSOR loop
- For each item, do data manipulation (Insert or Delete) - let's call this operation A
- For each item, insert an entry into a status table - let's call this operation B
- Loop ends (and iterates)
- Exit

Operation A takes are few minutes and Operation B takes just a fraction of second as it is just inserts 1 row into a status table.

So now the problem is, the status table in the operation B gets locked until all the 50 or so iterations complete.

I can give more background but this seems to be the crux of the problem. Pointers for solution will be really helpful (time sensitive).

What I tried - added explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` for operation happening in both A and B. Still it seems that the B status table gets lock after the first iteration and until all the iterations complete.

Comment: Just inserting a single row into a table (operation B) should **NOT** lock the entire table - yes, the newly inserted rows will be locked until the whole transaction is committed - but not the entire table ...

Comment: For each loop, the operation B is within a transaction. So only one row is inserted and the transaction is committed. Will the lock on B table continue to be held after the transaction is committed ? (Which is what seem to happen)

Comment: Does the select statement for the cursor involve Table B? Have you tried defining it as a `STATIC` cursor? Otherwise it seems like your begin/commit/rollback tran statements are unbalanced.

Comment: No, the CURSOR is just on a different list. Think of a comma separated text turned into a CURSOR.

Comment: Are SQL Server CURSORS known to continue to HOLD the locks even after a COMMIT TRANSACTION stmt ?
https://jayminsoni.com/2018/04/04/how-to-avoid-cursor-mssql-stored-procedures/

Comment: Did your initial implementation have an explicit transaction around operation B? Or was that an attempt to resolve the issue? Either way, I think we're at a point where we're speculating about the problem because we can't see your code and are talking to a description of it. It might be time to craft a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

So this SQL Procedure was initiated by a Python code via SQLAlchemy. The SQLAlchemy transaction had an over-arching tx that got committed only after the complete execution of theSQL Procedure. So all the transactions opened with the proc were child tx and did not effectively commit instantaneously (Child Tx commit only when the parent commit).

I solved this by Changing the Transaction type to AUTOCOMMIT in SQLAlchemy!